# PHP imap weird encoding characters

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, gmail, imap

I'm using PHP to get my gmail email messages. It gives me email titles which look like this:

```
=?ISO-8859-13?Q?Darba_s=E2k=F0ana_ar_Gmail?=
```

It should actually look like this (those are Latvian characters normally available in utf8):

```
Darba sākšana ar Gmail
```

I tried:

```
utf8_encode(quoted_printable_decode(
   "=?ISO-8859-13?Q?Darba_s=E2k=F0ana_ar_Gmail?="
));
```

And it gives me the following, which is not correct:

```
=?ISO-8859-13?Q?Darba_sâkðana_ar_Gmail?
```

How do I get this - Darba sākšana ar Gmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [imap_mime_header_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php) function:

```
$text = "=?ISO-8859-13?Q?Darba_s=E2k=F0ana_ar_Gmail?=";

$elements = imap_mime_header_decode($text);
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo "Charset: $element->charset\n";
    echo "Text: $element->text\n\n";
}
```

And you can use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function to convert:

```
iconv($element->charset, 'utf-8', $element->text);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Piotr answered, you need to use imap_mim_header_decode. I'm assuming that you are using the imap_headerinfo with fromaddress. This is what I did :

```
if (strpos($header->fromaddress,'?=')) {
    $wrong_charset = imap_mime_header_decode($header->fromaddress);

    $corrected_charset = '';

    for ($i=0; $i<count($value); $i++) {
        $corrected_charset .= "{$wrong_charset[$i]->text} ";
    }

}
else{
    $corrected_charset = $header->fromaddress;
}
```